# WPF: Is there an API can implement the same function of HorizontalSnapPointsType of ScrollViewer in Win8 App?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a property called HorizontalSnapPointsType which is for ScrollViewer in Win8. But I want the same function in Desktop App for Windows 7. Do we have the API for that?

Thanks a lot.